# Lift Web Framework modules

Tags: django, scala, module, lift

suppose you have 2 separate lift applications (CRM and shop). The shop depends on CRM (clients).

How do you connect them? In Django you just have to put it in INSTALLED_APPS setting tuple... Is there any similar mechanism for lift? Is it possible to build lift applications from such modules?

Thianks in advance,
Etam.

Answer (score 2):

Lift doesn't have any built-in capabilities to integrate applications, but you can follow common integation styles:

- **[Shared database](http://www.eaipatterns.com/SharedDataBaseIntegration.html)**: two applications are using one database;
- **[Remote Procedure Invocaton](http://www.eaipatterns.com/EncapsulatedSynchronousIntegration.html)**: SOAP webservices, EJB, CORBA, etc;
- **[Messaging](http://www.eaipatterns.com/Messaging.html)**: messaging middleware (Active MQ, Rabbit MQ, Redis Pubsub), Scala Remote Actors;
- **Shared Resources**: XML/JSON REST sevices;

Besides that, you can use Lift with [Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration) and [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) - frameworks that simplify integration of generic applications.

---

As I understand, Django modualarization you're referring to happens on a container level. Close altenatives in the JVM-ecosystem are [OSGi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) / [Jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/) (the second will probably be a part of JVM8).

Basic modularization these days is done with JARs/WARs/etc - specifically your applications should be archived as WARs and deployed separately to the app server.